# Unmap bash shortcut key

Tags: bash

So I happen to use Ctrl-S as my tmux prefix. I have disabled the terminal driver ctrl-s behavior with stty -ixon in my .bashrc

However, I see that bash also has a ctrl-s key map (I've been using zsh, so haven't run into this) that does forward search. How do I disable this key map? Forward search in bash isn't very useful to me.

Answer (score 1):

In ~/.inputrc, add a line:
`"\C-s": nop` .

This file is read by the readline(3) library, that bash uses, for key definitions.

After each change to ~/.inputrc, you can make the change active in the current bash environment by issuing a reread command: `\C-x \C-r`.